# Stopping a daemon in C

Tags: c, process, signals

My signal handler looks like:

```
volatile sig_atomic_t loop     = 1;

void handle()
{
    loop = 0;
}
```

And, I have a daemon which is like:

```
void _start_()
{
...
sa.sa_handler = handle;
sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL);
while(loop)
{
   //add a line to a file
}
...
}
```

I want to `stop` the daemon, from another function like:

```
void _stop_()
{
    raise(SIGINT);
}
```

My idea is, somehow if the value of `loop` is 0, then the `while` would be evaluated as false, and the daemon exits. 
I am planning to use these two functions like:

```
_start_(); //daemon starts
//computation
_stop_() //daemon stops writing to the file. exits
```

How can I achieve this? The problem is I am not able to stop the daemon from `_stop_()`.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to look at the program with a debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the _stop() function called from a separate process from your daemon? If so, then it needs to know the ID of the process to signal. Normal practice is that the daemon writes its process ID to a file (a PID file) which can the be read by the process that stops the daemon.

Comment: I have updated the question. The `_start_()` function is a daemon, and the `_stop_()` function tries to stop the daemon by raising a signal.

Comment: "Normal practice is that the daemon writes its process ID to a file (a PID file) which can the be read by the process that stops the daemon." - so are you intending that I could read the pid, and then from `_stop_()` I would just need to read and then kill the pid?